# TestRail Integration with XCUITest

Tags: swift, xcuitest, testrail

@Dimu4 I will really appreciate if you can add more details on the integration. I am trying to do the same with XCUITest, where I am trying to integrate with Bots so that for every test run I sent the test result to TestRail.

My questions:

how do you add testcase Id to each func testxyz() in XCUITest which is similar to the test case number in TestRail.
How do you generate a pre-build script to create TestRail test run?
How to link test run number and each test case id in my XCUITest?
I will really appreciate your help.

Comment: can you just post your questions and maybe remove the first part which seems irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

You might have to write a test rail client which talks to test rail inside your swift code. In your TestBase's tearDown method, you could invoke a method which would report to TestRail.

Refer here for test rail API V2 documentation : http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/start

Refer to this page on how to report your test result to Testrail http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/reference-results

Refer to this page on how to create a test run : http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/reference-runs

Answer (score 0):

There is better way to do (How i do in my current project)

1. Wrap all test rail API in a module
2. Instantiate this module once
3. IMplement protocol XCTestObservation in your base class (for test)
4. override methods like testBundleDidFinish, testCaseDidFinish, testCaseWillStart and use properities/ methods testCase.description testCase.name and call wrap apis of test rail to update test rail

This way you need not to modify any of your test, but when test start/end it will automatically call test rail apis and update test rail.